# Proxy exception in service but not app

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I make a web request from both an application and a service. From the application (user context), the request works fine. However, the service (LocalSystem context) catches this:

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.
```

Why can the application get out but the service can't? Do I need to import some proxy credentials into the service?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the Proxy: -

```
' proxy settings 
Dim cr As New System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "pwd", "MyDomain") 
Dim pr As New System.Net.WebProxy("127.0.1.2", 80) 

pr.Credentials = cr 
s.Proxy = pr
```

Cheers,

Phil.